# How do i search for a single row of data by id num?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to search for customer information by using ID numbers and is just printing the ID, Title, First Name row above the `inFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` line and then is skipping the while loop and going back to the enter customer ID again. Attached is an image of how it's set up in the CSV file (fake info, obviously:) )

[image: link to image]

I have a feeling I may be using the `inFile.Seek` wrong or the `recordIn` isn't getting the right data to work. All I want to do is just search for a single row of information by `ID` number and the print that subsequent row. Here is the code:

```cs
{
    const char DELIM = ',';
    const double END = 000;
    const string FILENAME = "D:\\customers.csv";
    Customer cus = new Customer();
    FileStream inFile = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inFile);
    string recordIn;
    string[] fields;
    int idNum;
    Write("  **Type " + END + " To Quit** Enter Customer ID Number> ");
    idNum = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
    while (idNum != END)
    {
        WriteLine("{0,5}{1,10}{2,15}{3,15}{4,15}{5,25}\n", "ID", "Title", "First Name", "Last Name", "Gender", "DOB");
        inFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
        while (recordIn != null)
        {
            string idd = cus.ID.ToString();
            string dob = cus.DOB.ToString();
            fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);
            idd = fields[0];
            cus.Title = fields[1];
            cus.FirstName = fields[2];
            cus.LastName = fields[3];
            cus.Gender = fields[4];
            dob = fields[5];
            if (cus.ID == idNum)
                WriteLine("{0,5}{1,10}{2,15}{3,15}{4,15}{5,25}\n", idd, cus.Title, cus.FirstName, cus.LastName, cus.Gender, dob); ;
            recordIn = reader.ReadLine();

        }
        Write("  **Type " + END + " To Quit** Enter Customer ID Number> ");
        idNum = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
    }
    reader.Close();
    inFile.Close();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :))

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `Customer` instance after split the lines, and also you need to skip first row since it's header:

```
{
    const char DELIM = ';';
    const double END = 000;
    const string FILENAME = "D:\\customers.csv";
    Customer cus = new Customer();
    FileStream inFile = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inFile);
    string recordIn;
    string[] fields;
    int idNum;
    Write("  **Type " + END + " To Quit** Enter Customer ID Number> ");
    idNum = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
    while (idNum != END)
    {
        WriteLine("{0,5}{1,10}{2,15}{3,15}{4,15}{5,25}\n", "ID", "Title", "First Name", "Last Name", "Gender", "DOB");
        inFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        reader.ReadLine();
        recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
        while (recordIn != null)
        {

            fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);

            cus.ID = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]);
            cus.Title = fields[1];
            cus.FirstName = fields[2];
            cus.LastName = fields[3];
            cus.Gender = fields[4];
            cus.DOB = fields[5];

            if (cus.ID == idNum)
                WriteLine("{0,5}{1,10}{2,15}{3,15}{4,15}{5,25}\n", cus.ID, cus.Title, cus.FirstName, cus.LastName, cus.Gender, cus.DOB);
            recordIn = reader.ReadLine();

        }
        Console.Write("  **Type " + END + " To Quit** Enter Customer ID Number> ");
        idNum = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
    }
    reader.Close();
    inFile.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"D:/customers.csv";
        const char DELIM = ',';
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
            string recordIn = "";
            int rowCount = 0;
            while ((recordIn = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                recordIn = recordIn.Trim();
                if(recordIn.Length > 0)
                {
                    if(++rowCount > 1) //skip header row
                    {
                        Customer cus = new Customer();
                        string[] fields = recordIn.Split(new char[] { DELIM});

                        cus.idNum = int.Parse(fields[0]);
                        cus.Title = fields[1];
                        cus.FirstName = fields[2];
                        cus.LastName = fields[3];
                        cus.Gender = fields[4];
                        cus.DOB = DateTime.Parse(fields[5]);

                        customers.Add(cus);
                    }
                }
            }
            reader.Close();

            //get id number
            Customer customer = customers.Where(x => x.idNum == 123).First();
        }
    }
    public class Customer
    {
        public int idNum { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    }


}
```