# Searching for a single row of data by id number and then printing to console from a csv

Tags: c#, csv

Im a C# newbie and im trying to build a customer management system for a project where I want to search for the customer by ID number, skip the title row, and then print the searched row to the screen before the user continues on. My csv file is set up like this:

**[ID][Title][firstName][lastName][Gender][DOB]**

**[0][Mrs][Jane][Doe][Female][1/1/1990]**

**[1][Mr][John][Doe][Male][1/1/1991]**

**[2][Ms][Sarah][Doe][Female][1/1/2010]**

and so on...

I have a feeling I may be using the `inFile.Seek` wrong or the `recordIn` isn't getting the right data to work because it's only printing the `WriteLine` above the `inFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Ive formatted the code and put all that you need in there so its easier to debug:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const char DELIM = ',';
            const double END = 000;
            const string FILENAME = "D:\\customers.csv";
            Customer cus = new Customer();
            FileStream inFile = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inFile);
            string recordIn;
            string[] fields;
            int idNum;
            Write("  **Type " + END + " To Quit** Enter Customer ID Number> ");
            idNum = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
            while (idNum != END)
            {
                WriteLine("{0,5}{1,10}{2,15}{3,15}{4,15}{5,25}\n", "ID", "Title", "First Name", "Last Name", "Gender", "DOB");
                inFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                reader.ReadLine();
                recordIn = reader.ReadLine();
                while (recordIn != null)
                {

                    fields = recordIn.Split(DELIM);

                    cus.ID = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]);
                    cus.Title = fields[1];
                    cus.FirstName = fields[2];
                    cus.LastName = fields[3];
                    cus.Gender = fields[4];
                    cus.DOB = fields[5];

                    if (cus.ID == idNum)
                        WriteLine("{0,5}{1,10}{2,15}{3,15}{4,15}{5,25}\n", cus.ID, cus.Title, cus.FirstName, cus.LastName, cus.Gender, cus.DOB);
                    recordIn = reader.ReadLine();

                }
                Console.Write("  **Type " + END + " To Quit** Enter Customer ID Number> ");
                idNum = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
            }
            reader.Close();
            inFile.Close();
        }

        public class Customer
        {
            public int idNum { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }
            public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        }


    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :))

Comment: FileStream.Seek breaks StreamReader because StreamReader has its own internal buffer. Therefore you should not be reusing StreamReader, you should create a new one after calling FileStream.Seek.

Comment: What is different from your 4/21 posting? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336746/how-do-i-search-for-a-single-row-of-data-by-id-num

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileStream.Seek` breaks `StreamReader` because `StreamReader` has its own internal buffer. Therefore you should not be reusing `StreamReader`, you should create a new one after calling `FileStream.Seek`

Here you have an example that doesn't reuse `StreamReader` and uses some Linq code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Customer
        {
            public int idNum { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }
            public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const char DELIM = ';';
            const int END = 0;
            const string FILENAME = "D:\\customers.csv";
            using (FileStream inFile = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  **Type " + END + " To Quit** Enter Customer ID Number> ");
                    var idNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (idNum == END) break;
                    inFile.Position = 0;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,5}{1,10}{2,15}{3,15}{4,15}{5,25}\n", "ID", "Title", "First Name", "Last Name", "Gender", "DOB");
                    foreach (var customer in GetCustomers(inFile, DELIM).Where(x => x.idNum == idNum))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0,5}{1,10}{2,15}{3,15}{4,15}{5,25}\n", customer.idNum, customer.Title, customer.FirstName, customer.LastName, customer.Gender, customer.DOB);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        static IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers(Stream input, char separator)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(input))
            {
                // read header
                reader.ReadLine();

                while (true)
                {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (line == null) yield break;
                    var fields = line.Split(separator);
                    yield return new Customer
                    {
                        idNum = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]),
                        Title = fields[1],
                        FirstName = fields[2],
                        LastName = fields[3],
                        Gender = fields[4],
                        DOB = Convert.ToDateTime(fields[5])
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```